How properness translates by GAGA?
If $X$ is a proper scheme over $\mathbb{C}$, then is it compact as complex manifold in the sense of GAGA?
Original question was that if there is a non-projective smooth compact variety over $\mathbb{C}$. It is known that there is a non-projective proper abstract variety, so original question is solved if former question is true.

An algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$ is proper if and only if it is compact in the analytic topology. This is Proposition 6 in Serre's GAGA paper: http://www.numdam.org/item/10.5802/aif.59.pdf

Oh I didn't expected it is a statement in Serre's original paper! Surprising.
